# What encryption generates this type of text?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, yahoo-messenger

I'm trying to decode a DAT file produced by Yahoo Messenger, which looks similar to the text below which I generated by opening an exe in Notepad:

```
‹
‹N€9 tè…ÀtäÿFöt‹FŠ ‹V‹NˆÿFÿNëÿFH‰F3À9Ft9Ft  ö…³   ;Øtsj÷ël;Øt%‹F‹N¶Dÿj Pÿ5@aÐMè5  …À„þÿÿ…Ûuƒ} tÇEø   jEPÿvÿvÿuøÿ5DaÐMÿÐM…Àu,ÿÐM=Y  tjðë…ÛtjöXë<3Àf‹F,ÇF.   ‰Eë‹E‹N…Étÿv2PÿÑëƒ~$ t
‹N(f‰ƒF(ÿF 3À‰F_[ÉÂ ÌÌÌÌÌƒù
u<r<Ÿ
```

I have tried few online tools that has various encryption algorithm like Blow-fish, DES, MD5 1-Way and other normal encryption like leet speak, rot-13 etc, but i found the generated text is normal readable but not the original one. I think its AES or RSA or Triple DES. Actually i am working on a utility that will read the Yahoo Messengers archive of the local. But when i open the local , I found a DAT file, with encrypted text as above.

**(UPDATE)**

As per venkyduded article "yahoo uses a simple XOR algorithm to encode the messages (so much for security !!) ". Any good link on XOR rversing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a question.

Comment: It made me smile though... happy days...

Comment: It should be nearly impossible to find the encryption algorith just by looking at the encrypted data. To find out how to read the DAT File, compare the file before and after adding one more line to the messenger or change some bytes and see what effect it produces. This is more cryptoanalysis than programming.

Comment: IMHO this doesn't look as ciphertext produced from a strong algorithm, there are too many repeated or almost-repeated blocks. It looks like obfuscated data put into some kind of structure.

Comment: Do you have the password and not the algorithm or are you missing both?

Comment: You got me jon. It was a text from exe opened in notepad. Just for example. But in my yahoo messenger, DAT file i found similar alien words.

Comment: @Jonas- missing both. Condition is "File is encrypted , i want to decrypt it to plain text"

Comment: @AmRan: you're telling us that expected us to "crack" some random data from inside and exe that has no meaning whatsoever? <sarcasm>Thanks</sarcasm>. Now, huh, the article in @mkeats answer (that you now mention in the question), already has code to show how to decode the messages (hint: `^` is the XOR operator in C, and the algorithm for decoding is the same as for encoding).

Comment: -1 this question lacks the potential to be helpful to others.

Comment: "It was a text from exe opened in notepad." - this question has nothing to do with encryption then.

Comment: The encrypted text was just for example. As for me both look alike. Same patterns of character, i have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo Messenger only encodes the data files. Take a look at http://www.venkydude.com/articles/yarchive.htm for details on the format of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can help you. Unfortunately strongly-encrypted data will be indistinguisable from random noise. I expect the NSA have statistics they can run on data to determine this but normal people like us are SOL.

Even if you did know the encryption mechanism you'd also need the key before you could make any sense of it, and again if the encryption is good enough it'd be very difficult / impossible to guess.

Your best bet would be to reverse engineer that part of Yahoo Messenger to see what it's actually doing and where it gets the encryption key from / where it stores it.

Answer (score 0):

> As per venkyduded article "yahoo uses
>   a simple XOR algorithm to encode the
>   messages (so much for security !!) ".
>   Any good link on XOR rversing.

One would need to know what the original value was XOR against.  One would also need to know some additional information, for example how many words were being XOR'ed at a time, the answer to your question is.

In order to get the inverse of an XOR value you have to simply XOR the value with the seed again.